# How retrieve all comments of all posts

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a Blog model, a Post model and a Comment model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=80)        
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_pages")
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), default=datetime.now)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), null=True, blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(_('body'))
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name="posts")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)     
    comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment)


class Comment(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    body = models.TextField(_('body'))
```

In a view I retrieve all post with this istruction:

```
    posts = blog.posts.all()
```

So my question is:

How can I retrieve all comments of all posts in the template ?

I have tryed this but the comments aren't displayed:

```
{% for post in posts %}

  {{ post.title }} 
  {{ post.body }} 

      {% for comment in post.comments.all %}

         {{ comment.body }} 

      {% endfor %} 

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just missed off the `all`.

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
{% for comment in post.comments_set.all %}
```

Comment: I get the same problem. I don't see the comments :(